# Android App crashes when Trying to Use UCanAccess

Tags: java, android, processing

I am trying to write an Android app using [Processing](https://processing.org/), and the app needs to communicate with an Access Database stored on the device. To do this, I am trying to use [UCanAccess](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ucanaccess/?source=typ_redirect) since Java 8 apparently dropped native support for this sort of thing. For whatever reason, since adding this code, running my app results in it crashing with the message "Unfortunately, My First Android App has stopped."

Why is this happening? Here is the portion of the code that relates to the question:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import net.ucanaccess.converters.TypesMap.AccessType;
import net.ucanaccess.ext.FunctionType;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection;
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver;

static class databasesHandler
{
  static boolean readFromDatabase(int uid)
  {
    try {
      Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:///sdcard/Android/data/accessDatabase.mdb");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      stmt.execute("SELECT saveVal FROM userVals WHERE userId = " + str(uid));

      ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
      boolean spotFilled = false;

      if (rs != null)
      {
        while (rs.next())
        {
          spotFilled = boolean(rs.getInt("gameSaved"));
        }
      }

      stmt.close();
      con.close();
      return spotFilled;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have placed the UCanAccess library along with its `lib` folder within the `code` folder of my Processing sketch, and prior to me making this change, the app ran perfectly.

Comment: We would like to help you but you have to provide some more info than "it doesn't work". What's the exception? Also notice that the odbc and so the jdbc:odbc driver has never been supported in no-windows operative systems.

Comment: @jamadei I do not get any exception. I just get a message on my trading device that the app has crashed. Also, I did not know that the `jdbc:odbc` driver was Windows-specific. I am sorry that I cannot provide more detail, but I have provided all that I can.

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output of your app when it crashes ?